# How to check if an specific logger exists in Logback

Tags: logging, logback

Basically I need to check if an specific logger exists so I can change its level. Something like the following pseudo-code:

```
Logger myLogger =  (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger( "com.logger.to.Change");

if ( validateThatLoggerExist (myLOgger))  // check logger effectively exist
   myLogger.setLeve(Level.NEW_LEVEL)     // Change logger log level
else
   throw new LoggerNotFoundExeption()   // do somethig
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    String loggerName = "com.logger.to.Change";
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory
                    .getILoggerFactory();
    Logger logger = loggerContext.exists(loggerName); //returns Logger if exists else returns null

    if(logger != null){
        logger.setLeveL(Level.NEW_LEVEL)
    }else{
        throw new LoggerNotFoundExeption()   // do something
    }
```